# Generate all possible lists from the sublist in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have list `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['1', '2']]`

I want to generate list where on the first place is any value from first sublist, on the second - from second etc.

So, a couple of examples:

```
['a', 'd', '1']
['b', 'd', '1']
['c', 'd', '1']
['a', 'e', '1']
['a', 'e', '2']
['b', 'e', '1']
['b', 'e', '2']
```

etc.

Comment: How long could the list be?

Comment: Why not just generate a random number (index) for each of the sublists and appending that character to a new list?

Answer (score 2):

You need [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which return cartesian product of inpur iterables:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> my_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['1', '2']]

#                v Unwraps the list
>>> list(product(*my_list))
[('a', 'd', '1'), 
 ('a', 'd', '2'), 
 ('a', 'e', '1'), 
 ('a', 'e', '2'), 
 ('b', 'd', '1'), 
 ('b', 'd', '2'), 
 ('b', 'e', '1'), 
 ('b', 'e', '2'), 
 ('c', 'd', '1'), 
 ('c', 'd', '2'), 
 ('c', 'e', '1'), 
 ('c', 'e', '2')]
```